# how to return multiple items from linq query

Tags: linq

Hi I have a method which i am calling to get the list of email of users , i am returning that list and my calling method is using these emails , I want to get the program title as well to pass with the list how to achieve that.

```
public static List<string> GetAllStudents(int? year,int? program,int? module,int? block)
        {
            var res = (from s in std.Student_courses
                       join p in std.Programs
                       on s.Program_Id equals p.Id
                       join sc in std.Students
                       on s.Student_id equals sc.Student_Id
                       where s.Program_Id == program && s.Year_Id == year && s.Module_Id==module && s.Block_Id==block
                       select new
                       {
                           
                           Email = sc.Student_Email,
                           Program=p.Program_Title
                           
                       }).ToList();
          
            List<string> EmailList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in res)
            {
                EmailList.Add(item.Email);

            }
            return EmailList;
            //var result = from userDistrict in std.Student_courses
            //             from district in std.Students
            //             where (userDistrict.Student_id == district.Student_Id) 
            //             select district.Student_Email;

          //  return std.Student_courses.Where(x => x.Program_Id == program && x.Year_Id == year && x.Module_Id == module && x.Block_Id == block ).ToList();

        }
```

Comment: You can return a Tuple of two lists or better define a new class that contains two properties for email an title, create a list of that class and return it

Comment: I cannot mix both values into a single list as one listing value is used as email to send email to the users.

Comment: check my code i am already doing that

Comment: basically where i want to use program title i am getting program id there already but i want the title not the id so i did select new {} with join to proram table, so how should i pass this to my calling method the program title along with email list.

Answer (score 0):

Using `new {}` creates an anonymous type which cannot be passed to a method or returned out of the method scope (even if it's inside a list).

You are returning a list of `string` values. I recommend you change this to a list of a new class that contains both the email and the Program properties.

```
public class EmailInfo
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Program { get; set; }
}
```

You can then return this class from your method:

```
public static List<EmailInfo> GetAllStudents(int? year, int? program, int? module, int? block)
{
    var results =
        from s in std.Student_courses
        join p in std.Programs on s.Program_Id equals p.Id
        join sc in std.Students on s.Student_id equals sc.Student_Id
        where s.Program_Id == program && s.Year_Id == year && s.Module_Id == module && s.Block_Id == block
        select new EmailInfo
        {       
            Email = sc.Student_Email,
            Program = p.Program_Title       
        };
       
      return results.ToList();
}
```

And use both values (as an example I've printed the values to the console):

```
var emails = GetAllStudents();

emails.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"'{x.Email}', '{x.Program}'"));
```

This could print the following to the console:

```
'email1@domain.com', 'title 1'
'email2@domain.com', 'title 2'
```